# Moderators can't reset a user's network profile

Tags: bug, profile-page, moderator-tools, moderators, network-profile

Moderators have the ability to clear a user's profile on our site, if it violates site policy.  We also have the ability to copy these changes to the user's profiles on other sites.

However, doing this apparently leaves the network profile unchanged.  This is surprising and unexpected.  It seems like a design flaw.

There are circumstances where a moderator needs to clear a user's profile (e.g., because it is abusive or violates our guidelines).  In those circumstances, we need to clear the user's network profile, too.  Moderators should be given that capability, without needing to contact a community moderator.  I don't see much of a risk or harm.

Also, when we need to clear a user's profile because of abusive content, there is no indication that clearing their profile leaves the network profile untouched, or that we need to contact a CM.  This is a trap for the unwary.

I'd go farther and suggest that in every situation where a moderator changes a user's profile and copies it to all other public sites, it should also change the network profile as well.

For moderators: I'm referring to the interface in the tab labelled "Edit profile and settings", and specifically the button labelled "Save and copy changes to all public communities".